# SwiftUI achieve Master and Detail structure in tvOS

Tags: swiftui

The way to achieve Master and Detail structure, as of beta 4, it should be by using .navigationViewStyle(.doubleColumn). Works perfectly on iOS / iPadOS / macOS but not in tvOS... it's a bug or I'm missing something?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var arra = ["Margherita","Marinara","Calzone"]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(arra, id: \.self) { pizza in
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(pizza: pizza)) {
                    Text(pizza)
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("MASTER")

            SecondView(pizza: arra[0])
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.doubleColumn)
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var pizza : String
    var body: some View {
        Text(pizza)
        .navigationBarTitle("DETAIL")
    }
}
```

[image: tvOS result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(as of GM release) The official doc tells something like: double column style will be stacked on tvOS, like it's an iPhone in portrait mode. So it's impossible to automatically achieve the "master and detail" look like it's an iPad in landscape, you have to build it for yourself. Even if you use one UISplitViewController in UIKit! With this behavior I think it's good to go only if the master it's a fullscreen CollectionView, sorta like Netflix App.